# How to run script on startup of a Fedora 14 machine

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, restart

I have an AWS AMI with Fedora 14 installed. I do not have root access but I can do pretty much anything using `sudo`. I have a script that I want to run on machine startup - `myScript.sh`.

This script is called by calling `sudo /dir/dir/myScript.sh start`. It also supports the commands `stop` and `status` which I use very often.

What is the ideal way to run such a script at startup?

Comment: `sudo` access usually means root access, as `sudo` lets you run commands as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mechanisms easily available:

The two most common mechanisms:

Adding an [upstart job definition](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) file. This looks easy, but does limit the distributions that can use your provided script to a handful of newer ones (Ubuntu, Google's Chrome distribution, Fedora, probably RHEL?).

Adding a [sysv-init initscript](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts). init-scripts are harder to write, but have much more flexibility in providing more command line arguments for sysadmins to use. They are also supported nearly everywhere, even distros which have switched (some or most) of their initscripts over to Upstart jobs.

I don't see it often, it is more a system-administrator choice than a software developer choice, but you can also use the system Vixie `cron(8)` facility to start programs at boot.

You can add entries to the system crontab in `/etc/cron.d/*`; Vixie cron supports a `@reboot` specifier which is excellent for this task.

Or, you can add an entry to your own personal `crontab(5)` file; again, Vixie cron's `@reboot` works for users too, but you cannot run an *interactive* `sudo(8)` from a `crontab(5)`. See the `NOPASSWD` documentation in `sudoers(5)` if you want to use your own personal `crontab(5)` file, but be warned the other admins on the machine may hate this idea.

Comment: I'm not sure. But wouldn't it be worth adding where to add/place those scripts Upstart/sysv-initscript?

Comment: @BleedingFingers: good idea. Since this answer was written, systemd has also come out and changed The Answer for several distributions, and that should be properly addressed...

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest and most universal method (although less flexible than @sarnold's suggestions) is to add `/dir/dir/myScript.sh start` to /etc/rc.local. The script will then be run on boot after all the other start-up scripts have run.

Comment: Note that Fedora 16 doesn't ship with `rc.local` by default anymore, but [it can be added manually](http://scrye.com/wordpress-mu/nirik/2012/03/30/rc-local-in-fedora/).